# Docker Disable legacy registry using osx

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I've uploaded a Docker image to a internal repository, the push seems to work fine but when i try to pull from it it says:

```
"{\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"status\" : 400,\n    \"message\" : \"Unsupported docker v1 repository request for 'docker-v2-global-local'\"\n  } ]\n}"
```

After some googling I've come accross the disable legacy registry options which is mentioned in the [docker daemon docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/). However trying to set it from the command line results in:

```
docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command.
```

If I ssh in to my docker-machine and try to update my /var/lib/boot2docker/profile it just gives me this is read only. By this point I'm not even sure that this option will help me but how do I actually set it?

Im using: 
OSX 10.10.4
Docker version 1.9.1
docker-machine version 0.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a machine (in your case a virtualbox boot2docker one) in which the docker daemon is configured with `disable-legacy-registry` option, you would need to type:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt disable-legacy-registry <name>
```

Comment: my man! I had tried with simply --disable-legacy-true when creating a machine. Silly me. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: How to do this with Docker for Mac?

Comment: @Leo You mean with the new docker for mac not using VirtualBox? That could be best answered ion a new question.